# How to remove special character being added after id in GTM Module in NuxtJS?

Tags: nuxt.js, google-tag-manager

Hi I am using @nuxtjs/gtm package for nuxt google tag manager and it seems in the noscript part there is a special character '&' being added?How do I remove the same?
"https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-WMVM48G&"

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the `&` is an added character and not part of the ID?

Comment: @kissu Yes as The tag ID is GTM-WMVM48G.Its showing GTM-WMVM48G everywhere else except this url in the noscript tag

Comment: @Teknoville do you have a screenshot where this noscript part exist?

Comment: @KhushalRajawat I have attached the screenshot from the Console showing the tag in the tree